# Typescript Array Push wiping string value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to build an angular app for a personal project and my first webform is exhibiting behavior I don't understand.  I have an interface as follows with a service to update an array of that interface.  The array is instantiated in the service from existing json.  My component uses a checkItemForm to hold the data, then onSubmit() updates an item and pushes that item using the service.  If I just pass this.newcheckitem, it is correctly handling the ID but the name only ever registers as and empty string.  If I pass a new object with the name and id separately the behavior works as expected.  What am I missing that is causing the name attribute to get wiped out?

Interface

```
export interface CheckItem {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Service

```
export class ChecksService {
  items: CheckItem[] = checkItems;  //Check items being an array of 2 check items held in assets
  constructor() { }

  addToChecks(checkItem: CheckItem){
    this.items.push(checkItem);
  }
}
```

Component in full

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { CheckItem } from '../check-item';
import { ChecksService } from '../checks.service';
import { checkItems } from 'src/assets/journaldata';
import { CheckItemComponent } from '../check-item/check-item.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-check-item',
  templateUrl: './new-check-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-check-item.component.css']
})
export class NewCheckItemComponent implements OnInit {

  private newCheckItem : CheckItem = {id: 5, name: "Why"};

  checkItemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    checkName : ''
  })
  
  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.newCheckItem.name);
    this.newCheckItem.name = this.checkItemForm.value.checkName!;
    this.checkItemForm.reset();
    console.log(this.newCheckItem.name);
    this.checkService.addToChecks(this.newCheckItem);
    this.checkService.addToChecks({id:5, name:this.newCheckItem.name})
    console.log(checkItems);
  }

  constructor(
    private checkService: ChecksService,
    private formBuilder : FormBuilder
    ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Console Output:

```
Why
TestName
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: 'Test'}
1: {id: 2, name: 'Another Test'}
2: {id: 5, name: ''}
3: {id: 5, name: 'TestName'}
```

Comment: Hello. Your question is very difficult to follow. Could you please update it to include your full component? For example, why does the array have four items in it when you've only added two?

Comment: And you manipulate the array at the end (this.newCheckItem.name = '') and don't console log after.

Comment: I have added some edits to try to bring clarity.  The array is instantiated based on a local JSON file.  I did just figure out what was happening though.  In clearing the newCheckItem name value for the next entry it was logging that value.  The code did not make sense so I will be removing the question.  Thank you for looking at it though!

Comment: Don't remove your question, your error could help someone having a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function `addToChecks` is adding a reference to the incoming `CheckItem` to your array, not a copy. Thus, when you reset the `name` of `newCheckItem` to be empty (`this.newCheckItem.name = ''`), the array is referencing the same object, and thus will show an empty name as well. Instead, what you can do is store a copy of the incoming parameter in your array:

```
  addToChecks(checkItem: CheckItem){
    this.items.push({ ...checkItem });
  }
```